# What is wrong with this binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to detect the update of a search field in ionic. This is the HTML code:

```
<ion-view title="Buscar Programa" style="background-size: 100% auto;">
<div ng-controller="searchCtrl" title="">
    <ion-content>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar" ng-model="searchEvents" ng-change="onSearchChange()">
        </label>
    <ion-content>
</div>
```

This is the JS controller:

```
myApp.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.onSearchChange = function () {
        console.log($scope.searchEvents);
    };
});
```

The function does get fired when text input changes, but log output is empty. When using JS alert, it just says 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to log?

Comment: Because `$scope.onSearchChange` is function not variable. Try to put some text

Comment: I am trying to print the contens of the input field. Sorry, I posted the wrong code, it is $scope.searchEvents, not the function name.

Comment: @kankamuso please find the duplicated answer, which has described why this behavior happening with detailed reasoning

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the "trick". This was an interesting response, didn't know the scope changed like this...